# Cut Filename and size from output (ls -l)

Tags: unix, awk, command, cut, ls

I am doing a script to do the following:

1. ruta: /etc

   - Mayor fichero: databig.dat (924873294 bytes)
   - Menor fichero: passwd (43213 bytes)
2. ruta: /home/asignaturas

   - Mayor fichero: so (4096 bytes)
   - Menor fichero: so (4096 bytes)
3. ruta: /lib

   - Mayor fichero: libx86.so.1 (5512945 bytes)
   - Menor fichero: networks (4096 bytes)

In this script, i need to show the name and size from the biggest file, same from the smallest, from the path that i give to the script, like this:
 "**./lsMinMax /etc /home /lib**"

My problem start when i try to cut only the name and it size. I got something like this: **drwxr-s--- 2 root dip 4096 feb 2 15:13 chatsripts**. I try to cut it using spaces as limiters but in the case of /etc i got the name, and in /home i got the date.

This what i have at this moment ( now i dont use cut, im trying using awk):
[script](http://i.gyazo.com/af74943a0d648f104309dc0a4b4916c4.png)

And this is my output:

[output](http://i.gyazo.com/2653cbb296305c018f2c448e752a0cdb.png)

I hope you can help me. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

As Shane hinted, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `stat` to query the files and sizes. I then use `awk` to parse `stat` output and determine the largest and smallest:

```
#!/bin/sh

lsMinMax () (
    cd "$1"
    echo "ruta: $1"
    stat -c "%s/%n" * | awk -F/ '
        NR == 1  { min = max = $1; minf = maxf = $2 }
        $1 < min { min = $1; minf = $2 }
        $1 > max { max = $1; minf = $2 }
        END {
            printf "   Mayor fichero: %s (%d bytes)\n", maxf, max
            printf "   Menor fichero: %s (%d bytes)\n", minf, min
        }
    '
)

for dir do
    lsMinMax "$dir"
done
```

Comment: This is a far better answer.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended from [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), do not try and parse the output of `ls`.

> the use of ls is just plain unnecessary. It's an external command
>   whose output is intended specifically to be read by a human, not
>   parsed by a script

Instead use `$i` inside the loop to get the filename.